# Infinite recursion in PHP echo statement

Tags: php, recursion, infinite-loop, tostring

Why does this code cause an infinite recursion?

```
class Foo {
    public static function newFoo() { return new Foo(); }
    public function __toString() {
        return "{${Foo::newFoo()}}";
    }
}

echo new Foo(); // Infinite recursion
new Foo();      // Finishes normally
```

Is this because `__toString()` is returning an object? But that can't be possible because according to the docs

> This method must return a string, as otherwise a fatal E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR level error is emitted. ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring))

Or does it just infinitely recurse within the `__toString()` method?

Comment: The method is returning a string, however the string it returns will be evaluated because you put double quotes around it. So the function signature is satisfied, it's returning a string. The evil part happens afterwards, because the string is being `eval()`d.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo new Foo();
```

creates a `Foo` and tries to `echo` it, to do so it casts the object to string invoking magic method `__toString`.

In that method, however, you invoke the static method `Foo::newFoo`, which returns a new object, which is again casted to string in `__toString` itself, which so gets called again.

So yes, here is infinite recursion.

To clarify:

```
public function __toString() {
    return "{${Foo::newFoo()}}";
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public function __toString() {
    $foo = Foo::newFoo();
    return "$foo"; // this is a cast as string, which invokes __toString() again.
}
```

Comment: The issue is that `__toString` must return a string. In OP's case, it does return a string but that string is enclosed with double-quotes so it's also evaluated, which is what causes the confusion. However, +1 from me.

Comment: @Mjh thanks for your opinion, I tried to edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Figured so. What a neat way to cause an infinite recursion. Thanks for the analysis, everyone too.

Answer (score 1):

Because your are calling it infinitely..

you echoed `echo new Foo();`

and you're calling it again with:

```
'return "{${Foo::newFoo()}}";'

public static function newFoo() { return new Foo(); }
```

here's a sample simulation:

```
echo new Foo();
```

will call this:

```
public function __toString() {
   return "{${Foo::newFoo()}}"; 
}
```

// and you called

```
public static function newFoo() { return new Foo(); }
```

// and will again execute

```
public function __toString() {
   return "{${Foo::newFoo()}}"; 
}
```

// and will again call

```
public static function newFoo() { return new Foo(); }
```

// and will again and again execute

```
public function __toString() {
   return "{${Foo::newFoo()}}"; 
}
```

// and will again and again call

```
public static function newFoo() { return new Foo(); }
```

**Ooooohhh** I'm in a infinite loop already, I'm just kidding..

But yes, this is an infinite loop..